# Issues with using wildcard in Makefile while build .ko from objects across directory

Tags: linux, makefile, wildcard, kernel-module, kbuild

I organized the kernel modules as different sub-component, so I can easily insert/remove existing sub-module to try or integrating stuff.

The directory layout is shown as below:

```
foo --+-- Makefile
      |
      +-- main.c
      |
      +-- include --+-- foo1.h
      |             |
      |             +-- ... (other headers)
      |
      |
      +-- src ------+-- foo1.c
                    |
                    +-- ... (other sources)
```

Here's my Makefile,

```
MODULE_NAME = foo
obj-m += $(MODULE_NAME).o

# [approach 1-1]
# SRCS := main.c src/foo1.c

# [approach 1-2]
SRCS := main.c $(wildcard src/*.c)

$(MODULE_NAME)-objs += main.o $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all:
        # [2] echo to check if foo-objs values changes
        echo $($(MODULE_NAME)-objs)
        KCFLAGS="-I$(PWD)/include" \
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I got warning shown as below when I tried to replace approach [1-1] with [1-2] in my Makefile above.

```
WARNING: "InitFoo1" [.../foo/foo.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "CleanuptFoo1" [.../foo/foo.ko] undefined!
```

From the console output, I **don't see the `src/foo1.c` got compiled** as if I am using approach [1-1] in Makefile.

```
# [2] echo to check if foo-objs values changes
echo main.o main.o src/foo1.o
main.o main.o src/foo1.o
KCFLAGS="-I/home/cyng93/experiment/issues/so_kbuild_wildcard/include" \
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.23-PT-ProbeOn-AuditOn+/build M=/home/cyng93/experiment/issues/so_kbuild_wildcard modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/linux'
  CC [M]  /home/cyng93/experiment/issues/so_kbuild_wildcard/main.o
  LD [M]  /home/cyng93/experiment/issues/so_kbuild_wildcard/foo.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "InitFoo1" [/home/cyng93/experiment/issues/so_kbuild_wildcard/foo.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "CleanupFoo1" [/home/cyng93/experiment/issues/so_kbuild_wildcard/foo.ko] undefined!
  CC      /home/cyng93/experiment/issues/so_kbuild_wildcard/foo.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/cyng93/experiment/issues/so_kbuild_wildcard/foo.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/linux'
```

I try to echo `foo-objs`(check [2] in Makefile) and found out that the value are the same for both approach [1-1] & [1-2].

Does anyone on SO has came up with similar issues can help to shade some light on ?

*(I prefer [1-2] because it can save my effort from updating the Makefile when new sub-component is added)*

Below I also attached the source code of `main.c`, `foo1.c` & `foo1.h`.
You can also check the [github repo for this issue](https://github.com/cyng93/experiment/tree/master/issues/so_kbuild_wildcard) for easier access to those code.

---

#### main.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include "foo1.h"


static int myinit(void)
{
    printk("Module inserted!\n");
    InitFoo1();

    return 0;
}

static void myexit(void)
{
    CleanupFoo1();
    printk("Module removed!\n");
}

module_init(myinit);
module_exit(myexit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");
```

Here, `foo1` is a sub-component, where simply print out some stuff during its intialization and cleanup:

#### ./include/foo1.h

```
#ifndef FOO1_H
#define FOO1_H

int InitFoo1(void);
void CleanupFoo1(void);

#endif
```

#### ./src/foo1.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include "foo1.h"


int InitFoo1(void)
{
    printk("Init Foo1\n");
    return 0;
}


void CleanupTest(void)
{
    printk("Cleanup Foo1\n");
}
```

---

#### update_2018/01/15

According to Tsyvarev answer below, one can correct the Makefile by modifying Makefile as below:

```
MODULE_NAME = foo
obj-m += $(MODULE_NAME).o

# [approach 1-1]
# SRCS := main.c src/foo1.c

# [approach 1-2 (not working)]
# SRCS := main.c $(wildcard src/*.c)

# [approach 1-2 (working)]
MISC := $($(src)/wildcard src/*.c)
SRCS := main.c $(MISC:$(src)%/=%)

$(MODULE_NAME)-objs += main.o $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all:
        # [2] echo to check if foo-objs values changes
        echo $($(MODULE_NAME)-objs)
        KCFLAGS="-I$(PWD)/include" \
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Based on what you've shown here I can't explain this behavior.  You should invoke make with the `-p` option to have it dump its internal rules and make sure that the `src/foo1.o` files are listed as prerequisites where you'd expect them, and invoke make with the `-d` option to see what it does and why it's not building `foo1.o`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these tricks that can help to have better understanding on stuff happen behind the make process. :)
But I believe the main reason I struggled in this issues in due to lack of the understanding in KBuild flow. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When build the kernel module your `Makefile` is processed **twice**:

1. When you type `make` from your module's directory.
2. Inside Kbuild process, because you pass `M=$(PWD)` option to it.

First time the Makefile is processed with current directory equal to the *module's directory*. So wildcard works as expected, which is confirmed by printing from `all` receipt.

But the second time the Makefile is processed with current directory equal to **kernel's build directory** (`/lib/modules/4.4.23-PT-ProbeOn-AuditOn+/build` in your case). In that mode

```
$(wildcard src/*.c)
```

attempts to find a file in kernel's build directory, which obviously fails.

---

At the time of second processing one may refer to module's build directory with `$(src)`.

Such way one may use `wildcard()` for collect module's sources. But note, that Kernel build system expects path to source file (more precisely, to *object* file) to be **relative to module's build directory**. So, one need to strip `$(src)` component of every file obtained with `wildcard()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this critical point on kbuild flow!
By the way, is it a good practice to use $(src) instead of $(PWD) when referring to *module's build directory*, or they are not likely to make any difference?

Comment: `is it a good practice to use $(src) instead of $(PWD) when referring to module's build directory` - I am not sure, but at the second Makefile's processing `$(PWD)` would refer to *kernel's build directory*, so you have no choice other than use `$(src)`.